# How to convert a Django queryset containing DateTimeField into a Pandas datetime index?

Tags: python, django, pandas

I have a model with a DateTimeField and I would like to create a datetime index with it. The idea is to then compare the datetime indexes with another datetime indexes called `ranges`.

The model is very simple:

```
class Candle(models.Model):
    dt = models.DateTimeField()
```

The Pandas datetime index :

```
start = timezone.make_aware(datetime.combine(date(2018, 1, 1), datetime.min.time()))
end = timezone.now().replace(minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
ranges = pd.date_range(start=start, end=end, freq='H')

print(type(ranges))
<class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>
```

The Django QuerySet :

```
dt = Candle.objects.filter(market=m).values('dt')

print(dt)
<DataFrameQuerySet [{'dt': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 2, 6, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {'dt': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 2, 5, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {'dt': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 2, 4, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {'dt': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 2, 3, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {'dt': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 2, 2, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {'dt': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 2, 1, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {'dt': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 2, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {'dt': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 23, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {'dt': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 22, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {'dt': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 21, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {'dt': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 20, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {'dt': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 19, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {'dt': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 18, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {'dt': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 17, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {'dt': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 16, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {'dt': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 15, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {'dt': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 14, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {'dt': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 13, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {'dt': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 12, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {'dt': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 11, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
```

So my question is how can I convert the queryset `dt` into a datetime index so I can compare it with `ranges` ?

Answer (score 1):

I answer to my own question because I found the solution:

```
index = pd.DatetimeIndex([idx['dt'] for idx in Candle.objects.filter(market=m).values('dt')])

print(type(index))
<class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>
```